# Heroku python deploy error. Forcing postgre when I'm using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, heroku, pip

I am having a problem when deploying my python app to heroku. It worked some weeks ago, but now I get the following error:

`Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from -r /tmp/build_4da55df137eec05ceddf34ca700ab233/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/a8/dc2d50a6f37c157459cd18bab381c8e6134b9381b50fbe969997b2ae7dbc/psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            running egg_info
remote:            creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
remote:            writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:            writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:            writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:            writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.5'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4o1vw6rl/psycopg2/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed`

I am using the default heroku build package. I don't understand why it is trying to install psycopg2-2.6.2, I don't have it in my requirements file, I'm actually using mysqlclient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your requirements file?

Comment: requirements.txt
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.11.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
whitenoise==3.2
mysqlclient==1.3.12
djangorestframework==3.6.4
django-debug-toolbar==1.8
django-cors-headers==2.1.0